Isolate several devices from the rest of the LAN
I moved a web application from the cloud to a Raspberri Pi cluster in my basement. The network looks like this:

The cluster is connected to a TL-SG1016DE switch. I installed a Kemp Load balancer on a QEMU/KVM hypervisor on a laptop (configured as bridge), which redirects the traffic forwarded from gateway on port 443 to the webserver on k3s.
I want to isolate all devices related to the web server from the rest of the network, to limit the exposure in case of a security breach of the web server. On my switch I have this config window:

But I don't understand 802.1Q VLAN configuration. If I tag all webserver devices on VLAN-2 but untag or un-member them from VLAN-1 my web application becomes unreachable. Let's say I want to isolate devices on ports 12-16 from the rest of the network.
How should I configure the switch?
Do I need to configure network on the devices as well?


If I tag all webserver devices on VLAN-2 but untag or un-member them from VLAN-1 my web application becomes unreachable. Let's say I want to isolate devices on ports 12-16 from the rest of the network.

If you do this, you indeed isolate those ports from the main network – the problem is that you also isolate them from the router (which is still in VLAN 1), so naturally they become unreachable.
But also, the correct setting for those servers would usually be an untagged port (i.e. VLAN 1 not member, VLAN 2 untagged). Both "tagged" and "untagged" ports are member ports; the difference is that "tagged" literally inserts an 802.1Q VLAN tag into the Ethernet header, which the connected device must understand and generate.
So in general only the port facing your router should have the extra VLANs as tagged. Ideally you need a 802.1Q compatible router, which would let you create virtual "tagged VLAN" Ethernet interfaces over its physical ports, allowing it to send/receive multiple VLAN traffic from the switch over a single cable – a "trunk" port.
Then you'd configure the router with a 2nd IP subnet for the new "VLAN 2" interface, and set up firewall rules on the router to allow the VLAN 2 subnet to talk to the Internet but not to the VLAN 1 subnet.
(It's also relatively common to use  tagged VLANs with hypervisors; the hypervisor handles 802.1Q tagging for each VLAN's traffic, allowing some VMs to be isolated from others. Less common for ordinary servers and even less so for workstations, but not impossible.)

So, I've brushed on VLANs a little a bit. It seems that my Netgear R7800 router doesn't actually support VLANs, even though it claims that it does and it doesn't have firewall to separate VLANs even if I create them on my managed switch. So I can't really achieve what I wanted unless I spend $300 on a pfsense router. Anyway, thanks for the help.

@Viktor: In that case, run a pfSense VM (or some other router VM) on your hypervisor, as any decent hypervisor will have support for VLANs. The router VM should have two interfaces, one on each VLAN (usually easier to let the hypervisor handle VLAN tags than to pass a whole trunk to the VM). The Netgear should have a static route to the 'VLAN 2' subnet via the router VM.

Yes, $300 was over-exagerated. I considered getting an old M720Q and add a 2-port 2.5Gb ethernet card to it, but that would add up to around $180. So I am just thinking about getting a Protectli Vault V1210-2 Port for $220 instead and  setting-up pfSense on it, but I will look into these other options you suggested. I was curious if that was possible to setup a second VM on my hypervisor (I am assuming I would need a second nic), but I am lacking proper skills to configure vlans and bridges on HV. I will see if I can find good manuals for that on the internets.
